# How can I integrate sumup api in a website?

Tags: php, sumup-payments

I have a problem integrating SumUp payments on a web site. I am working in a test enviroment.

Here are the steps:

1. I create an access token. This appears to be correct.
   The response is:  ‘at_classic_mCw3yDX1pjGZG7atysF3HhDpdvIvhykuhVbOGqaxoyrKor4Wf12R4’ (example)
2. I create a checkout. This appears to be correct.
   The response is:

```
Array
(
    [checkout_reference] => 65cee380da447
    [amount] => 2.5
    [currency] => GBP
    [pay_to_email] => 1143da2*************798@developer.sumup.com
    [merchant_code] => MC*****C
    [merchant_country] => GB
    [merchant_name] => 1143da2d-21ba-4ec1-a4f0-3bebd2d88798
    [description] => Sample one-time payment
    [id] => c56bb3bb-ea2a-4c90-9f06-e28d839778f1
    [status] => PENDING
    [date] => 2024-02-16T04:24:33.000+00:00
    [purpose] => CHECKOUT
    [transactions] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

3. I complete the checkout at the target url of: https://api.sumup.com/v0.1/checkouts/c56bb3bb-ea2a-4c90-9f06-e28d839778f1
   The response is:

```
Array
    (
        [amount] => 2.5
        [checkout_reference] => 65cee380da447
        [currency] => GBP
        [date] => 2024-02-16T04:24:33.000+00:00
        [description] => Sample one-time payment
        [id] => c56bb3bb-ea2a-4c90-9f06-e28d839778f1
        [merchant_code] => MC*****C
        [merchant_country] => GB
        [merchant_name] => 1143da2d-21ba-4ec1-a4f0-3bebd2d88798
        [pay_to_email] => 1143da2*************798@developer.sumup.com
        [purpose] => CHECKOUT
        [status] => PENDING
        [transactions] => Array
            (
            )
    
    )
```

As you can see from the last response, the checkout does not complete. The ‘[transactions]’ array is empty.
This is the php code I use to complete the checkout:

```
************** Start code **************

// complete checkout
$packet_payment = [
  "payment_type" => "card",
  "card" => [
    "name" => "Boaty McBoatface",
    "number" => "4200000000000042",
    "expiry_month" => "12",
    "expiry_year" => "24",
    "cvv" => "123"
]];
$headers_payment = [
  'Content-Type: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization: Bearer '.$api
];
$packet_json_payment = json_encode($packet_payment);

$target_url = "https://api.sumup.com/v0.1/checkouts/".$output_checkout1['id'];

$ch_payment = curl_init();
$ch_payment = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch_payment, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch_payment, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $packet_json_payment);
curl_setopt($ch_payment, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_payment, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_payment);
$output_payment = curl_exec($ch_payment);
$output_payment1 = json_decode($output_payment, true);

************** End code *********
```

I have contacted the integration team at SumUp, but not much luck so far.

Any help greatly appreciated.

George